# Why does the comb of Natasha Otomoski have 21 teeth?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, hash-signature

What is the signature size of Natasha Otomoski haircomb? What is the number of invocations of the underlying one way hash function for key generation, signature, and verification?

How does it compare to the recently standardized variant SPHINICS+?

Comment: The title of this question does not appear to match its body.

Comment: Ooouh, it's because I'm new :) and I have soo many questions about the comb.

Comment: I closed this question because it does not come with enough context to be intelligible. Also, previous mentions of NOH have been promotions of a cryptocurrency-related concept, and call me paranoid but I'm afraid this could be.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Signature size: 672 bytes

Public key: 32 bytes

Hash invocations, verification: 59213 + 1

Hash invocations, keygen: 21 * 59213 + 1

Hash invocations, sign: 21 * 59213

Comment: I believe it is 20 * 59213 hashes for signing, isn't it? You only need to reach the cut and not the handle.